# Appbar's title not working on setstate in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text(gazung),
        backgroundColor:  Color(0xffDBDDE0),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xff9CA2B0),
              ),
              child: Text('2021-02 개정 기준'),
            ),

            ListTile(
              tileColor: Color(0xffDBDDE0),
              title: Text('2021-02 개정 기준'),
              onTap: (){
                setState(() {
                  gazung = 'changedaapbartext';
                });
```

I output the title of the app bar as a variable called gazung and setstate in the drawer to change it, but it is not applied to the title of the appbar.

Comment: Hi! Can you share some more code? I can't replicate the issue, as it works fine for me.

Comment: String gazung = 'beforetitle';
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xffDBDDE0),
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text(gazung),
        backgroundColor:  Color(0xffDBDDE0),
      ),

Comment: drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xff9CA2B0),
              ),
              child: Text('2021-02 개정 기준'),
            ),

Comment: ListTile(
              tileColor: Color(0xffDBDDE0),
              title: Text('changeappBarText'),
              onTap: (){
                  setState(() {
                    gazung = 'changeappbartext';
                  });
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

Comment: Adding to the comments, the code is messy. I'm sorry

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this code, i did not get any issue.

```
class ApBarTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const ApBarTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ApBarTest> createState() => _ApBarTestState();
}

class _ApBarTestState extends State<ApBarTest> {
  String gazung = 'Title';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text(gazung),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffDBDDE0),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xff9CA2B0),
              ),
              child: Text('2021-02 개정 기준'),
            ),
            ListTile(
                tileColor: Color(0xffDBDDE0),
                title: Text('2021-02 개정 기준'),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    gazung = 'changedaapbartext';
                  });
                })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: body: Center(
        child: Stack(

Comment: I used stack on the body, so this is not the cause, right? still doesn't work

Comment: After taking the variable declaration and setstate out of @ovvride, that's it. thank you very much

Comment: Thank you for accepting even if I ask a strange question

Comment: No problem brother you are most welcome.